# Formulario de contacto php smtp no envia correos a servidor

Tags: php, iis, phpmailer

Hola que tal el problema es el siguiente un servidor www.elcodigo.com maneja los correos por otro server que es correos.elcodigo.com que usa Outlook Web Access el formulario html consta de tres archivos envia.php class.phpmailer.php class.smpt.php cuando lleno el formulario envia el phplog tira:
todo bajo el servidor iis

```
 PHP Warning:  mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;http://correo.elcodigo.com&quot; port 587, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wwwroot\formulario-contacto\envia.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no cuentas con un servidor de correo, te recomiendo SendGrid es muy bueno y tiene su versión free y su documentación es muy completa, te dejo el enlace de como implementarlo en PHP.

Saludos y espero te sirva

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html